# How to Configure MongoDB Collection to Persist in RAM and Disk?

Tags: mongodb, persistence, persistent-volumes

First, is it possible to have a collection to persist both in RAM and disk storage?

If so, how do I configure it to do so using a node API?

Comment: No, apart from https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use

Comment: So if my machine has 100GB RAM while the total size of my database is only 10GB, how do I configure it so that 100% of all the collections of the database is always cached?